# Year to Date and Quarter to Date calculations in SSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I'm building SSAS cube for financial data and would like to have YTD (year to date) and QTD (quarter to date) calculations. I am beginner in this, so have googled around. Many advice not to use built in Time intelligence, but instead create MDX calculations. So I have read more and finally tried to build it up using example. It works, but I am not sure if I am not overdoing it. Also, I would like to use Cubeformulas in Excel to extract values, however my current formual is a bit complicated, contains array... Here is example of Excel formula `=CUBEMEMBER("ServerName";{"[Dim Date].[CalHierarchy].[Year].&[2014].&[2].&[4]"\"[TimeCalc].[TimeCalc].[YTD]"}))` .

And here is actual Calculation Script I added to the cube:

```
CALCULATE;   

-- Create the calculated members
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[TimeCalc].[TimeCalc].[YTD]
 AS Null, 
VISIBLE = 1;  
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[TimeCalc].[TimeCalc].[QTD]
 AS Null, 
VISIBLE = 1;    

-- Scope for the specific Measures 

Scope({[Measures].[Amount]});    
Scope([Dim Date].[Quarter].[Quarter].members,[Dim Date].[Date Key].members);    
    -- QTD CALCULATIONS
    ([TimeCalc].[QTD]=
        Aggregate(  
            CrossJoin({[TimeCalc].[Current Period]},
                PeriodsToDate([Dim Date].[CalHierarchy].[Quarter],
                [Dim Date].[CalHierarchy].CurrentMember)
                    )
            )
    );    
    End Scope;   Scope([Dim Date].[Year].[Year].members,[Dim Date].[Date Key].members);    
    -- YTD CALCULATIONS
    ([TimeCalc].[YTD]=
        Aggregate(  
            CrossJoin({[TimeCalc].[Current Period]},
                PeriodsToDate([Dim Date].[CalHierarchy].[Year],
                [Dim Date].[CalHierarchy].CurrentMember)
                    )
            )
    );    
    End Scope;    

End scope;
```

I have created one extra dimension called TimeCalc, which is linked to main Time dimension called "Dim Date". Would it be simpler if I create two separate extra dimensions? One for YTD calculation and one for QTR calculation? Then perhaps my retrieve formula would not have complicated array structure?

Comment: like you mention there are many references to the native functions. Like this on: http://aniruddhathengadi.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-calculate-ytd-qtd-mtd-and-wtd.html   or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095242/mdx-query-how-to-compare-year-to-date-figures-from-the-current-year-with-year-t

Comment: yes, there are several different solutions, that I am not able to understand or verify which one is better or worse. Seems like I am very close to what I want to achieve with my cube calculations, just have somewhere small adjustment  to do, that I hope somebody with MDX and SSAS knowledge can help me with.

Comment: personally I do not use our Time Calculations dimension but I create custom measures and members within each report tailored to the specific report. Not a generic solution but at least the mdx is within my control.

Comment: I would 100% suggest adding your question to MS's own SSAS forum here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=sqlanalysisservices  Response time is slower but some "heavy-weights" of SSAS, answer questions on that forum, whereas StackO is quick it is not so in depth re. SSAS and MDX.